# How to change the function parameter to point?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I want to modify the following code, changing the `Input` to a pointer.
But keep the function of recursion.

```
int FunctionA(int Input)
{
    int Output;
    if (Input == 1)
        return 1;
    if (Input < 1)
        return -1;
    Output = Input + FunctionA(Input-1);
    return Output;
}
```

How do I modify the code?

I have tried to modify like the following, but I want to know does there has better method.

```
int a, Output = 0;
a = *Input;
cout << a <<endl;
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    Output = Output + i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @Martin Wun: Why don't you read the pointer concepts online first?

Comment: Could you explain why you need a pointer? That might lead to better answers.

Comment: I have try the code like the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following?

```
int FunctionA(int *Input)
{
    int Output, InputRec;
    if (*Input == 1)
        return 1;
    if (*Input < 1) 
        return -1;
    InputRec = *Input - 1;
    Output = *Input + FunctionA(&InputRec);
    return Output;
}
```